# Passing data from my hybrid Ionic 2 App to the inAppBrowser

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic2, inappbrowser

I need to pass some data ( Login-Name and Password ) to some website, which I open with the inAppBrowser.

I save the data before into the IOS - keychain.

When I open the inAppBrowser via a button, the first page, which is shown is this login page. At the 2 fields, i want to insert the data from the keychain.

Is it possible to do that? And if it is, how do I do?

I’m using ionic v2.

Thank you in advance

ps
I think I saw something working for ionic v1, but nothing for v2.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `InAppBrowser` to send a url with the parameters as your url queries

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

username:string;
password:string;

var openBrowser(url){
 let browser = new InAppBrowser('url', '_self'); //change it to _system if you want to open in System Browser
}

this.openBrowser('http://yourwebsite.com/api/action?username='+this.username+'&password='+this.password);
```

And then in your website you can just take the values from the query and fill those values into your username and password input fields.

Comment: thank you for this advice, but sadly I can't do anything to the code of the website at all

so I can't send the URL simply with the parameters